# How do you add labels in Trello?

Tags: trello

I created a new Trello account, and then board. In my board, I created a list, and in my list, I created a card.

When I open the card, I don't see any way to add a label.

How do I add a label to the card?

[image: Trello no labels]

Comment: I cannot reproduce what is shown on your image. In our cards, the menu shows more options, including the labels option. Could you share a link for the card? Is this behavor consistant?

Comment: Likewise I can't reproduce your issue. If you press "l" (lower case L) while viewing the card, does the pop-over menu appear [per Trello's label guide](https://help.trello.com/article/797-adding-labels-to-cards)?

Comment: @marikamitsos It doesn't happen in my old Trello boards. To reproduce, create a new account. It seems they stopped allowing labels on free accounts

Comment: Tried it but all works fine. Since yours is a new account as well, try creating another test one and see what happens.